# How to keep css id to the 'li' in css

Tags: html, css

The below vertical navigation work perfect but. i would like to change the html code from

```
<ul id="menu">
<li ><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li ><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li ><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li ><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
<li id="menu" ><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li id="menu"><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li id="menu"><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
<li id="menu"><a href=""><span>Hello</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

It doesn't works. I would like to keep the id for li not for ul . Is i pass id to li ,it doesn't show the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7hdB/

```
#menu ul
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#menu a
{
display: block;
color: #333;
height:30px;
font-size:12px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;

border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 2.72em;
line-height: 2.75em;
text-indent: 2em;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover
{

background:#ffffff;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); 
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff),  color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); 
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff',  endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); 
 color:#266CAE
}
#menu li a{ background:url('http://s11.postimg.org/dmj1ubnrz/button22.png') no-repeat ;
 background-position:0% 50%;
}

#menu li a:hover{ background:url('http://s7.postimg.org/ajm07zk2v/button33.png') no-repeat   ;
background-position:0% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us why you would like to change the html code? What is the concrete problem?

Comment: I had another id <li id="menu2"> , so by using php i would like to keep menu2 id for some lists.

Comment: As people have pointed out, two elements cannot share the same `id`, but they can share the same `class`. So the second piece of code you posted is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant have more than 1 item with the same id, you will want to give the li a class of "menu"... then in your css change "#menu li a" to ".menu a"

Answer (score 0):

For a start `id` should be unique

What you are looking for is `class`

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong and `ID` must be used one time!!

but see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z7hdB/4/